# Redirect webpage from server to android in webview

Tags: php, android, html, webview

I'm working on a webapp using `Android WebView` which uses `php` files on server. I want the page to redirect user to page on the android app. Here is my code for `login.php`:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$usernm = "root";
$passwd = "";
$databs = "dbname";
$Conn = mysqli_connect($server, $usernm, $passwd, $databs);
$email_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn, $_POST['e_mail']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn, $_POST['pass_word']);
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$email_id' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($Conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$active = $row['active'];
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1) {
# session_register("email_id");
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $email_id;
header("location: https://google.com"); # I want the header to send user to local page on android
} else {
$error = "LOGIN AND PASSWORD NOT FOUND ON RECORD";
}
?>
<div><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

Comment: Sorry this is a bit unclear to me,  are you asking how to open an activity in your app from the web browser application? Or go to some other url that might be local to device?

Comment: I want the `php` page on my server to navigate to local webview page in my android app. I want the functionality like payment apps. The payment apps navigate to online payment gateway and come back to android app. Is there any way to do it?